# How to create Sequence Number and ACK in a Python 2.7 UDP socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, header, udp

I have the code below. Right now I am just putting the `sequence number` and `ACK` in the payload. I would like to know two things:

1. How can I put this info into the header for both client and server?
2. How can I print out the ACK on the client and Sequence number on server?

I am using Python 2.7.13 on Linux.

---

**Client:**

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client_socket.settimeout(4.0)
message = "Sequence Number: 100\nACK: 1"
addr = ("127.0.0.1", 6000)

client_socket.sendto(message, addr)
try:
    data, server = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    # Print the ACK the server sent
except socket.timeout:
    print('Timed out')
```

---

**Server:**

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 6000))

while True:
    message, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    # Print the sequence number the client sent
    # Set ACK to 0 and send this ACK to the client
    server_socket.sendto(message, address)
```